# what is the standard output foreman?

Tags: java, logging, jetty, foreman

I have the following Java code

```
System.out.println(client.resource(RESTFUL_URL_DISCIPLINAS));
        System.out.println(client.resource(RESTFUL_URL_DISCIPLINAS).path(id.toString()));
        System.out.println(client.resource(RESTFUL_URL_DISCIPLINAS).path(id.toString()).path("curso"));
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(RESTFUL_URL_DISCIPLINAS).path(id.toString()).path("curso");
```

Why not display anything when I use the following command:

```
┌─[ricardoramos]@[falcon]:~/Projetos Eclipse/LOCAL-ClienteREST
└──> $ foreman start
19:21:45 web.1  | started with pid 19740
19:21:45 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:45.879:INFO:omjr.Runner:Runner
19:21:45 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:45.880:WARN:omjr.Runner:No tx manager found
19:21:45 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:45.917:INFO:omjr.Runner:Deploying file:/home/ricardoramos/Projetos%20Eclipse/LOCAL-ClienteREST/target/ClienteREST-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war @ /
19:21:45 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:45.943:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
19:21:46 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:46.495:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
19:21:48 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:48.167:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2438ms
19:21:48 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:48.517:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:!RequestLog
19:21:48 web.1  | 2015-07-01 19:21:48.542:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082
```

What's wrong?

Comment: For starters `jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT` means you are running an unstable, not vetted, direct from source control, version of Jetty.  (and [an old EOL / End of Life version](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) at that)

Comment: I'm using the 8.1.15.v20140411 version in my pom.xml file, tested the 9.2.5.v20141112 version, but it did not work, you have any suggestions? By using the correct version will be able to see my prints?